# Insertar varios valores en una fila, en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Quisiera saber el como puedo hacer que una fila pueda almacenar varios valores; mi base de datos se refiere a un taller, quisiera que al ver las características de un vehículo vinculado pueda también observar los servicios que a los cuales será sometido el vehículo, no se si me doy a entender.

Answer (score 0):

En principio podría haber dos opciones:

1. En la tabla correspondiente, crear una columna para cada valor que desees almacenar. Cada columna tendrá su propio formato según el tipo de dato que vaya a contener (CHAR, VARCHAR, FLOAT, INT, etc). Es el acercamiento más clásico. Estos valores pueden referir a un identificador único de otra tabla, o directamente el valor explícito...hay varias maneras de encararlo.
2. En la tabla correspondiente, crear una columna para almacenar todos los datos que necesites pero de manera estructurada. Esto se puede hacer con el tipo de dato JSON, y almacenando los datos, obviamente, en una estructura JSON. Este acercamiento al problema es flexible, porque puedes tener, llegado el caso, datos diferentes para diferentes registros y no es necesario tener una columna para cada posible dato, pero es más complejo en varios aspectos (por ejemplo, si será necesario actualizar un valor entre los datos, o buscar entre los datos, etc) porque deberás implementar funciones MySQL específicas a JSON, y a veces tiene sus complicaciones. Si es solo guardar y luego leer, puede ser muy práctico. En PHP puedes pasar fácilmente un `array` a `json` con la función `json_encode` y a la inversa con la función `json_decode` (para esta última, añadir el parámetro `true`, [ver documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias tener varias tablas, algo como esto

Tabla Vehiculo
Campos id_vehiculo, km, id_marca, color ...

Tabla Caracteristica
Campos: id_caracteristica, nombre

Tabla Servicio
Campos: id_servicio, nombre

debes llenar las tablas de caracteristicas y servicios con todos los que tengas y luego lo relacionas con los vehiculos

Tabla: vehiculo_caracteristica
Campos: id_vehiculo, id_caracteristica

Tabla: vehiculo_servicio
Campos: id_vehiculo, id_servicio

en estas dos tablas almacenas todas caracteristicas y servicios de cada vehiculo

Para traer las características y servicios de los vehículos lo haces con un query

```
select km, color, c.nombre, s.nombre
from vehiculo v
inner join vehiculo_caracteristica vc on vc.id_vehiculo=v.id_vehiculo
inner join caracteristica c on c.id_caracteristica = vc.id_caracteristica
inner join vehiculo_servicio vs on vs.id_vehiculo=v.id_vehiculo
inner join servicio s on s.id_servicio = vs.id_servicio
```

Si lo quieres traer solo para un vehículo le agregas al mismo query

```
Where v.id_vehiculo=<id_vehiculo>
```

donde <id_vehiculo> es parámetro del id_vehiculo